# Receive Image from pointer

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, parse-platform

I have a pointer in my parse. The pointer tells me who uploaded the images.  I am trying to retrieve the username and the profile picture of the uploader. To do that I have put        `query.includeKey("uploader")` . Users are managed through the user class. and posts are managed in the posts class. To retrieve the images and names I have the below code.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell
    let item = self.votes[indexPath.row]





    // Display "initial" flag image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.postsImageView.image = initialThumbnail

    if let pointer = item["uploader"] as? PFObject {
        cell.userName!.text = item["username"] as? String

    }

    if let profile = item["uploader"] as? PFObject {

    cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground({ (image:UIImage, error:NSError) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            cell.profileImageView.image = image
        }
    })}

    if let votesValue = item["votes"] as? Int
    {
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votesValue)"
    }

    // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
    if let value = item["imageFile"] as? PFFile {

        cell.postsImageView.file = value
        cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                cell.postsImageView.image = image
            }
        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

However errors are happening saying that loadinbackround can't be invoked with an argument list of type (UIImage, NSError)->void. The strange part is that the error is only for the first part where I try to retrieve the images for the user.  I am really stuck in this and want help. Is my pointer retrieving wrong? Thank you.

UPDATE 2

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.includeKey("pointName")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(question:[AnyObject]?,error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil
        {
            if let allQuestion = question as? [PFObject]
            {
                self.votes = allQuestion
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }


    // Wire up search bar delegate so that we can react to button selections

    // Resize size of collection view items in grid so that we achieve 3 boxes across

    loadCollectionViewData()
}

/*
==========================================================================================
Ensure data within the collection view is updated when ever it is displayed
==========================================================================================
*/

// Load data into the collectionView when the view appears
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    loadCollectionViewData()
}

/*
==========================================================================================
Fetch data from the Parse platform
==========================================================================================
*/

func loadCollectionViewData() {
    // Build a parse query object
}

/*
==========================================================================================
UICollectionView protocol required methods
==========================================================================================
*/

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.votes.count
}



func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("newview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewCollectionViewCell
    let item = self.votes[indexPath.row]





    // Display "initial" flag image
    var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
    cell.postsImageView.image = initialThumbnail

    if let pointer = item["uploader"] as? PFObject {
        cell.userName!.text = item["username"] as? String
        print("username")

    }

    if let profile = item["uploader"] as? PFObject,
        profileImageFile = profile["profilePicture"] as? PFFile {
            cell.profileImageView.file = profileImageFile
            cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground { image, error in
                if error == nil {
                    cell.profileImageView.image = image
                }
            }
    }

    if let votesValue = item["votes"] as? Int
    {
        cell.votesLabel?.text = "\(votesValue)"
    }

    // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
    if let value = item["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
        println("Value \(value)") 
        cell.postsImageView.file = value
        cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                cell.postsImageView.image = image
            }
        })
    }

    return cell
}
```

In my post class it is like this [image]
The users are managed in the user class. I want to get the profile image and username of the person who posted the image. 
In the user class I have all the user information. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your `loadInBackground` method with the below:

```
cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({ (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            cell.postsImageView.file = value
            cell.postsImageView.image = image
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you its now ok something weird happened and the error went away. However still can't  retrieve the profile image and username from parse. The pointers are not working

Comment: See the edited answer, and can I know why you are checking "error != nil" ? @Satsuki

Comment: no true meaning I changed to == . But the error went away with the previous code, still can't  retrieve the profile image and username from parse. updated question for more code

Comment: @Satsuki please see the edited answer, I have added else part

Comment: no log has come out.  To be clear the postImageView is fine. It is showing the images. However I can't get the images from the pointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85173/discussion-between-satsuki-and-sohil-r-memon).

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground({
        (image: UIImage!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
if image != nil {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                cell.postsImageView.image = image
})
}else{
           println("Image not available")
        }

        }else{
           println(Image Downloading error: \(error))
        }
    })
```

Try this , i think this will help you :)

Comment: hello Thank you for your answer. the post images are ok. The problem is that I can't retrieve the profile image and user name.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues here, the first being the way you pass the closure to the `loadInBackground` method

The compiler error is because you're trying to call the method with non-optional closure parameters.
In the `cell.postsImageView.loadInBackground` call you use optionals, while in the `cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground` you don't.
Closure parameter types are important, that's why the compiler is complaining.

I'd suggest skipping the types and defining the closure like this:

```
cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground { image, error in
    if error != nil{
        cell.profileImageView.image = image
    }
})}
```

The other and probably your main issue is that you don't set a file for the profile. So, if we say that the profile image is stored under `imageFile` in the uploader object, you would use:

```
if let profile = item["uploader"] as? PFObject,
    profileImageFile = profile["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
        cell.profileImageView.file = profileImageFile
        cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground { image, error in
            if error == nil {
                cell.profileImageView.image = image
            }
        }
}
```

Though, as the Parse documentation says, the method downloads and displays the image:

> Once the download completes, the remote image will be displayed.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFImageView.html#//api/name/loadInBackground:

If you don't need any special error handling and since you already have a placeholder image, try loading the image like this:

```
if let profile = item["uploader"] as? PFObject,
    profileImageFile = profile["imageFile"] as? PFFile {
        cell.profileImageView.file = profileImageFile
        cell.profileImageView.loadInBackground()
}
```

Comment: Thank you I still can't retrieve image from user. I get an error saying  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "profilePicture" has no data.  Is  query.includeKey("uploader") correct?

Comment: Yep, you should use call `includeKey`. Can you update the post with the structure of the profile class? Did the compilation error go away?

Comment: yes the compilation error went away but have another error saying'Key "profilePicture" has no data.  I have included the whole class so that you can see. I don't know why it doesn't go fetch the data from the pointer

Comment: this is in objective-c.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85183/discussion-between-bojan-dimovski-and-satsuki).